# Occasional performance issue

Tags: postgresql

I have such a query. I want to get the freshest car from a specific garage.

```
SELECT cars.* FROM cars WHERE cars.type = "hybrid" AND cars.garage_id = 7777 ORDER BY cars.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

`cars` table contains approximately 90 million records. Also, there is an index `index_on_garage_id` on `cars.garage_id`

Everything is fine, but sometimes it takes about 1 min to execute that query.

Here is the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`:

```
Limit  (cost=376.50..376.50 rows=1 width=507) (actual time=6.687..6.689 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3950
  ->  Sort  (cost=376.50..378.40 rows=762 width=507) (actual time=6.686..6.687 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=3950
        ->  Index Scan using index_on_garage_id on cars  (cost=0.57..372.69 rows=762 width=507) (actual time=0.027..5.263 rows=3935 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (garage_id = 7777)
              Filter: ((type)::text = 'hybrid'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 46
              Buffers: shared hit=3950
Planning Time: 0.205 ms
Execution Time: 6.719 ms
```

Additional info:

1. records are selected from the read replica.
2. there were no writes to the master at the time query was executed for a long time. (UPDATED)
3. there are no other queries that may lock the table.
4. Postgresql Version 12.5

I am running out of ideas and asking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your current query holistically, you generally would want an index which at least covers the entire `WHERE` clause.  In this case, it would be ideal if that index could also cover the sort in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Consider using this multiple column index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON cars (garage_id, type, id);
```

The way this index works, given that your query is searching for exact values for `garage_id` and `type`, is that a subtree of the entire B-tree index would be isolated given the `WHERE` clause.  Then, within that subtree, Postgres can immediately find the record with the highest `id` value, since the subtree is also sorted by `id` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

index field order also importand; first field must be `type` because of where clause

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON cars ( type,garage_id,id);
```

Comment: Note that InnoDB will by default include the `id` column at the end of every index automatically.